# Alguien me ayuda con un ejercicio en java

Tags: java

el ejercicio es el siguiente:

Hacer una clase de nombre Cajero que contenga las variables privadas nombreCliente, apellidoCliente, codigocliente y saldo.  En la misma clase declarar un método que permita abonar un depósito de dinero al saldo y otro método que permita retirar dinero, ambos métodos tendrán un parámetro.

Hacer otro método que me muestre la información siguiente:   Código Cliente:  Nombre y Apellido del Cliente:  El saldo total en su cuenta es:  Hacer otra clase que pruebe la clase Cajero instanciando 2 objetos, los datos de las variables NO serán capturadas desde teclado sino asignados directamente.  Para un objeto invocar el método abonarSaldo y para el otro el método retirar.  Al final invocar el método que me despliegue toda la información para cada instancia.

Solo he desarrollado hasta el saldo total de la cuenta
la otra parte que me piden que  clase que pruebe la clase Cajero instanciando 2 objetos, los datos de las variables ahí ya me quede :(

```
import java.util.*;

class cajero
{ 
    String NombreCliente, ApellidoCliente, CodigoCliente;
    double SaldoCliente;


    private void CapturarDatosAbono(double abono)
    {
        Scanner datoscliente = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Digite el monto a abonar a la cuenta: ");
        abono = datoscliente.nextDouble();
        SaldoCliente = SaldoCliente + abono;
    }


    private void CapturarDatosRetiro(double retiro)
    {
        Scanner datoscliente = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Digite el monto a retirar de la cuenta: ");
        retiro = datoscliente.nextDouble();
        SaldoCliente = SaldoCliente - retiro;
    }


    public void capturardatosabono()
    {
        CapturarDatosAbono(SaldoCliente);
    }


    public void capturardatosretiro()
    {
        CapturarDatosRetiro(SaldoCliente);
    }


    public void mostrardatos()
    {
        System.out.println("Codigo del Cliente: "+CodigoCliente);
        System.out.println("Nombre Completo del cliente: "+NombreCliente+" "+ApellidoCliente);
        System.out.println("Saldo total de la cuenta: "+SaldoCliente);
    }
}

class cajeroinstanciado
{

}
```

Comment: Hola Richard, te recuerdo que StackOverflow en Español no es un servicio de escritura de código, te recomiendo le eches un vistazo al artículo de [¿Como hacer una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Intenta hacer el ejercicio, y cuando tengas dudas especificas, podremos ayudarte con mejores respuestas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Según la descripción de tu problema, creo que lo que no podías solventar era hacer la prueba de la clase sin usar el Scanner, aquí tienes una propuesta utilizando un booleano para saber si estas probando la instancia, o realmente vas a pedir el monto por Scanner:

```
//Tu clase no tenía constructor, recuerda que el constructor se utiliza normalmente para inicializar las variables
public Cajero(String nombre, String apellido, String codigo){
        NombreCliente = nombre;
        ApellidoCliente = apellido;
        CodigoCliente = codigo;
    }


    public void CapturarDatosAbono(double abono, boolean probando)
    {
//Si no se esta probando (bool probando = false) se utilizara el scanner
        if(!probando){
            Scanner datoscliente = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Digite el monto a abonar a la cuenta: ");
            abono = datoscliente.nextDouble();
        }

        SaldoCliente = SaldoCliente + abono;
    }


    public void CapturarDatosRetiro(double retiro,boolean probando)
    {
        if(!probando){
            Scanner datoscliente = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Digite el monto a retirar de la cuenta: ");
            retiro = datoscliente.nextDouble();
        }
        SaldoCliente = SaldoCliente - retiro;
    }
```

Y en una clase main, puedes probar tu clase Cajero de la siguiente forma:

```
static Cajero intancia1, intancia2;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        intancia1 = new Cajero("Karlo", "Lopez", "kalm1997");
        intancia2 = new Cajero("Richard", "Alas", "RAL2017");  
        metodoParaProbar(intancia1);
    }

    public static void metodoParaProbar(Cajero instanciaAProbar){
        System.out.println("Comienza la prueba: " + instanciaAProbar.NombreCliente);
        //Probamos los ingresos
        for(int i = 0; i<10;i++){
            //Ingreso aleatorio desde 0 hasta 100
            int ingresoAleatorio = (int) (Math.random() * 100);
            instanciaAProbar.CapturarDatosAbono(ingresoAleatorio, true);
        }

        for(int i = 0; i<10;i++){
            //Retiro aleatorio desde 0 hasta 30
            int retiroAleatorio = (int) (Math.random() * 30);
            instanciaAProbar.CapturarDatosRetiro(retiroAleatorio, true);
        }
        instanciaAProbar.mostrardatos();
        System.out.println("Termina la prueba");
    }
```